# How to specify the type information of an array that would hold SwiftUI custom views

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am learning SwiftUI and I do understand that to create a view element using SwiftUI framework, your custom type must conform to 'View' protocol. I have a requirement where I want to declare an array which would hold custom SwiftUI components that I would be creating by making a Struct implementing the 'View' protocol. Now I am not sure what to mention as the type of the array since, providing 'View' as the type is giving the compiler error as "**Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements**".

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var tabs : [View]
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not SwiftUI-ty direction... try to use instead array of model (or view model) objects and depending on them create corresponding view in body.

Comment: Take a look at Apple's tutorials: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

Comment: Why are you trying to store an array of views on another view? What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo of possible approach to generate different views depending on some model enum. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
enum CustomTabDescriptior: Int {
    case one = 1
    case two = 2
    case three = 3

    var label: String {
        "\(self.rawValue).square"
    }

    // can be used also a function with arguments to be passed inside
    // created corresponding views
    var view: some View {
        Group {
            if self == .one {
                Text("One")    // << any custom view here or below
            }
            if self == .two {
                Image(systemName: "2.square")
            }
            if self == .three {
                Button("Three") {
                    print(">> activated !!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DemoDynamicTabView: View {
    let tabs: [CustomTabDescriptior] = [.one, .two, .three]
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(tabs, id: \.self) { tab in
                tab.view
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: tab.label)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I was trying to build a custom TabView where I would be able to able to pass in some parameter and dynamically build the tab bar. I was approaching this problem with my experience  of building something similar using UITabBarController. That was the reason for using the array holding view components. Your code gave me the right approach in SwiftUI. Thank You!!. And the compiler error was related to the usage of a 'protocol with associated type' as the type of a variable and this is not something specific to SwiftUI.