# How to have multiple destinations in a NavigationLink

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `NavigationView` configured and I'm trying to determine which view to send the user depending on what they picked.  I have four different files we can call ClassicLiftsView.swift, SFF1.swift, SFF2.swift, & SFF3.swift.  Currently I have the destination set to one file.

```
struct ProgramList: View {
    @State var showUpdate = true

    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                    NavigationView {
                        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                            HStack {
                                ForEach(programData) { program in
                                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                                        NavigationLink(destination:
                                        ClassicLiftsView()) {
                                            ProgramsView(program: program)
                                            .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees:
                                                Double(geometry.frame(in: .global).minX - 50) / -30
                                            ), axis: (x: 0, y: 10.0, z: 0))
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .frame(width: 275, height: 375)
                                }
                                .onMove{ (source: IndexSet, destination: Int) in
                                    programData.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
                                }
                                .padding(10)
                                .padding(.bottom, 30)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                            }
                        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Weida Programs"))
                    }
            }
    }
}


struct ProgramList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProgramList()
    }
}

struct ProgramsView: View {
    var program: Program

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(program.title)
                .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold))
                .frame(width: 160, alignment: .leading)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()
                Image(program.logo)
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 36, height: 36)
            }

            Text(program.text.uppercased())
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .foregroundColor(.black)

            Image(program.image)
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 210)
                .cornerRadius(5)
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 20, x: 0, y: 20)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.top, 20)
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        .frame(width: 275, height: 350)
        .background(program.color)
        .cornerRadius(30)
        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.4), radius: 20, x: 0, y: 20)
    }
}

struct Program: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var text: String
    var logo: String
    var image: String
    var color: LinearGradient
}

var programData = [
    Program(title: "So Fit 1.0", text: "12 Week Program", logo: "Weida", image: "program1", color: LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7540688515, green: 0.7540867925, blue: 0.7540771365, alpha: 1)), Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019754, green: 0.2745098174, blue: 0.3019607961, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)),
    Program(title: "So Fit 2.0", text: "12 Week Program", logo: "Weida",  image: "program2", color: LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7540688515, green: 0.7540867925, blue: 0.7540771365, alpha: 1)), Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019754, green: 0.2745098174, blue: 0.3019607961, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)),
    Program(title: "Classic Lifts", text: "Classic Training Program", logo: "Weida", image: "program3", color: LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7540688515, green: 0.7540867925, blue: 0.7540771365, alpha: 1)), Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019754, green: 0.2745098174, blue: 0.3019607961, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)),
    Program(title: "The Weida Way", text: "Classic Training Program", logo: "Weida", image: "program4", color: LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7540688515, green: 0.7540867925, blue: 0.7540771365, alpha: 1)), Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019754, green: 0.2745098174, blue: 0.3019607961, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)),
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by *depending on what they picked*? Picker where and what?

Comment: Sorry within NavigationLink(destination:....  I don't want each option in the scroll view to go ClassicLiftsView().  Here's a video if that helps https://photos.app.goo.gl/mVtBycTQB493PSHw5

Comment: If I correctly understood you need some enum with corresponding views like in the following for tabs (for links can be done the same) https://stackoverflow.com/a/62950510/12299030

Comment: Or in general dynamic router approach as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62909832/12299030